# How to combine Google Analytics with Relational Database

Tags: sql, analytics

I have a website with quite a lot of registered users, they are stored in a PostgreSQL database. I also running Google Analytics on the website to track the users. Is there a way to individually combine the GA data with the registration data from the website, e.g. finding out the e-mail address of a user we found in GA?

Also, is there a way for non-technical people to access the SQL database without knowing SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Just from my experiences you usually don't want people that don't know databases directly accessing a database. At the very least not a non technical person. Your users definitely shouldn't ever have direct access. Could you explain what you are looking to accomplish regarding the SQL question?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I want to give business people an easy option to generate insights out of the database without SQL skills. Like a visualization tool or data extractor.

Comment: The usual method for this is through reporting tools such as Crystal Reports (shiver). There are a lot of options but in general business people are not great at sql and should not have write privilege that does not go through an intermediate layer.

Comment: Great! Is Crystal Reports the recommended choice?

Comment: Really depends on how complex your reports need to be. Its a beast. If they are simple it might be easier to roll your own rather than learning the ins and outs of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using some tool. Such questions are on topic only if they cover how the tool integrates into some development *process* – after all, this site is about Software Engineering. See our [help/on-topic] for details. Please read: [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7253)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to individually combine the GA data with the registration data from the website, e.g. finding out the e-mail address of a user we found in GA?

Yes, there is a way. You can set custom variables to your visitors: [Custom Variables @ GA docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables)

So, for example, if you want to identify your logged-in visitors by their emails, you should programmatically add this JS on the page (e.g. when the user logs in):

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
     1,                   // Slot #1
     'email',             // Variable name
     'email@example.com', // Variable value
     1                    // Scope = visitor-level, optional
]);
```

It doesn't matter which type of DB engine you use, GA doesn't work with it directly anyway.

---

> is there a way for non-technical people to access the SQL database without knowing SQL?

You can provide them a user interface which they can understand and work with.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a great help! About the first question: What I'm looking for is to eventually be able to calculate correlations between say, one variable from GA and one in the database. Is that possible?

Comment: Furthermore, when I insert the JS to the page, how can I identify the individual user inside Google Analytics? Doesn't GA aggregate all the data and forbids identification of single users?

Comment: @user1684645 "calculate correlations" is a vague description. As for identification - if you set an email var in GA, isn't it enough to identify a user?